# How to reset a form in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, reset

I'm working in AngularJS with a very simple form that only has a textarea input and a submit button. The textarea is a required field. Everything works... until I've submitted the form. When I remove the value from the model after submitting the form, this triggers my validation errors. If I don't set the value to null or an empty string, the textarea retains the entered value, which is not what I want.

```
<form name="notesForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="vm.addNotesForm(notesForm)" novalidate>
<div control-validator="" validator-condition="vm.hasTriedToSubmit">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <!-- hidden field workaround for validation for textarea -->
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenNewNote" name="hiddenNewNote" required ng-model="vm.newNote.note" />
        <textarea id="newNote"
                  name="newNote"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Note"
                  ng-disabled="vm.isWorking"
                  ng-model="vm.newNote.note"
                  rows="3"></textarea>
        <control-validator-message>Note is required.</control-validator-message>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-disabled="vm.isWorking">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
            Add Note
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" ng-show="vm.isWorking"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since validation only works for input fields, the hidden field is necessary.

```
this.notesService.addNote(this.newNote).then(() => {
    this.notificationService.success('Successfully added new AR Note');
    this.isWorking = false;
    this.newNote.note = null; // <- This is where it goes sideways.
    this.refreshDataTable();
}, errorMessage => {
    this.notificationService.error(errorMessage);
    this.isWorking = false;
});
```

I've tried all sorts of solutions. I used the FormController to set the form to pristine and untouched - no luck. I saw a proposed solution where the controls on the form were programmatically set to 'undefined'. Still no luck. Either the form submits and my value stays there in my textarea, or I set the note to null/empty string, and the validation errors get set off as if I've tried to post without a value in the textarea. As a total hack I even tried using jQuery to set the value of the textarea to an empty string, while keeping the model state undisturbed. While this did appear to work, since the value is still stored in the model, if a user clicks the add button again, it reposts. Not what I need. I'd think this would be a cinch, but after an hour of looking for an answer online, I've come up with nothing that works.

Comment: Can you set this.newNote.note = '' and add a check on the function that sends the http request if this.newNote.note === '' return. I'd also add the 'required' attribute to your textarea.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant when asking about the return. I'm not having any trouble with model binding. The form submits and persists changes to the database without problems. My problem is clearing the form after submission has taken place. About the required field on the textarea, because Angular only likes to validate input fields, it doesn't need this attribute. That's set on the hidden field, which is how I get the validation to fire correctly. I just need a way to clear my form after submission that doesn't trigger my validation errors.

Comment: you need to reset the form validation object also

Comment: charlietfl - Can you provide an example or link? I've tried resetting the validation in several different ways, none of which have worked. In my addNotesForm() function, I'm accepting a param of type IFormController. I've tried $commitViewValue, $setPristine, and $setUntouched in isolation, together, and in various combinations, but no luck. Searching online to find a solution for resetting validation didn't yield anything else.